# Using slice in a multiple loop ngFor angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, slice, ngfor

Need to slice the inner ngfor loop into 3 parts

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of matrix; index as i">
 <div class="col" *ngFor="let col of row; index as j">
  <div *ngFor="let placeholder of placeholders | slice:i:j">
   <ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="placeholder.component" > 
   </ng-container>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue here? This should work from what I can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways around this:

$any

```
<p *ngFor="let item of data | slice:2:4">
  {{ $any(item).parentName }}
</p>
```

Bracket notation

```
<p *ngFor="let item of data | slice:2:4">
  {{ item['parentName'] }}
</p>
```

A function

```
slicedData(data : any[]) : any[] {
  return data.slice(2,4)
}

<p *ngFor="let item of slicedData(data)">
  {{ item['parentName'] }}
</p>
```

Comment: Modified bit by sending row and column parameters to slicedData method. Thank you so much.